# Adding z-index to week rows in FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, z-index

I'm trying to add a detail dropdown on events and they are getting cut off by the next row.

Is there anyway to set the z-index of each week row (.fc-row) in the monthly view so that each subsuquent row has a lower z-index? i.e. the first week has a z-index of 9, the second week has one of 8 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the markup, this could be done with javascript / jQuery:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $("tr.fc-row").length; i++) {
   $(".fc-row:eq(" + i + ")").css("z-index", ($("tr.fc-row").length - i));
}
```

This applies in case all `.fc-row`s on the page should get a lower z-index; in case this would only apply for all `.fc-row`s in a specific container having a specific class, e.g. `.fc-month` or `.fc-table`, this could be easily adjusted in the script.

**Update:** For the follow up issue that the z-index values get reset/removed when changing views - I just checked the documentation and found a solution for it. It's possible to add the `eventAfterAllRender`-callback - http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventAfterAllRender/  - to your current settings.
As example, when initializing the fullcalendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  /* your current settings */
  eventAfterAllRender: function()
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < $("tr.fc-week").length; i++) {
     $(".fc-week:eq(" + i + ")").css("z-index", ($("tr.fc-week").length - i));
    }
  }

});
```

`eventAfterAllRender` is called whenever the view is completely rendered, so it's only necessary to add the function here and it will add the z-index values for first view and whenever the view is changed.

Just created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/tsbLby4e/) as example: When you check the rows with web developer tools you'll notice the z-index values that'll be set for each week row, initially as well when changing the view to previous or next month.

Though this seems to work like intended, it could be better to only call this function when the month view is changed - there's another callback `viewRender` - http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/ - that is

> triggered when a new date-range is rendered, or when the view type
>   switches

Though I haven't tested it, the documentation mentions that this callback accepts `ViewObjects` as parameters, with `ViewObjects` having an attribute `name` that is one of the available views, like e.g. month. But maybe the suggested approach using `eventAfterAllRender` is already working for you.

As reference: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/viewRender/

Also updated the setting of the z-index values, previous version was incrementing instead of setting the highest value for the first row and decrementing.

Comment: Thanks with a little tweaking I got it to work. 

However whenever I switch views the z-index gets reset again, any ideas?

Comment: @BillYudichak Glad that it already worked for you. For the follow up problem with the z-index reset I've just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! viewRender works well for the month view, however I was having z-index issues on agendaWeek and agendaDay where I needed to use eventAfterAllRender.